# isSelected() , isDisplayed is not working for me in selenium,java for checkbox. Where xpath doesn't show if it is checked or unchecked

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

isSelected() , isDisplayed is not working for me in selenium,java for checkbox. Where xpath doesn't show if it is checked or unchecked.

> ```
>          <input aria-label="Resi" checked="checked" class="curam-checkbox " 
>          id="__p3id" name="__p3id" title="Resi" type="checkbox" value="true">
>             <label aria-hidden="true" 
>            class="checkbox-touchable-area" for="__p3id" 
>             title="Resi">&nbsp;</label>
> ```

```
         @FindBy(xpath="//label[contains(@title,'Resi')]")
         private WebElement resiCheckbox;



        public void clickResi() throws Exception {
        waitUntilTheElementIsVisible(resiCheckbox);
        if(!resiCheckbox.isSelected())
        resiCheckbox.click();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Show example of your java code, so we can help you.

Or try as show in example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("__p3id")).isSelected;
```

In addition. Try this:

```
    //Driver initialized by Chrome browser driver
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //Creating wait driver. In constructor we passing WebDriver by the first parameter
    // and max time to wait in seconds by the second parameter
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

    //Loading URL
    driver.get("Your URL");

    //Finding checkBox WebElement by id
    WebElement resiCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("__p3id"));

    //Waiting element to be clickable (max time to wait = 5 sec)
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(resiCheckbox));

    //Clicking if checkBox toggled off
    if(!resiCheckbox.isSelected())
        resiCheckbox.click();
```

Comment: Nice) What your code for finding element "resiCheckbox"? And how works your method "waitUntilTheElementIsVisible"?

Comment: waitUntilTheElementIsVisible  method works fine..           @FindBy(xpath="//label[contains(@title,'Resi')]")
 private WebElement resiCheckbox;

Comment: tried this but my isSelected() is showing as false always.

Comment: By which value you initialize "resiCheckbox"?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!resiCheckbox.getAttribute("checked").equals("checked"))
resiCheckbox.click();
```

or

```
if(!resiCheckbox.getAttribute("value").equals("true"))
resiCheckbox.click();
```

One of them should work.

Comment: I tried these both are not working. I tried it toggle on to toggle off but throwing null pointer.

Comment: Is the element in an iframe?

Comment: Yes it is in iframe and I switched to proper frame.

Comment: Wait, your xpath is referring to the label tag. The element you're trying to interact with has the input tag. You xpath needs to be: 
    //input[@title='Resi']